# Elasticsearch won't update results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I'm using Elasticsearch 6.6.0 and elasticsearch-py 6.3.0. I put some data into Elasticsearch, then made this little function to return a list of all the values of a particular variable in Elasticsearch:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch
def get_prior_records():
    records = es.search(
        index="my_index",
        body={"query": {"match_all": {}}, "_source": ["var_i_want"]})
    return [item["_source"]["var_i_want"] for item in records["hits"]["hits"]]
```

The first time I run this function, it works perfectly and returns a list of all the instances of `var_i_want` in the DB. However, when I add more data to the DB (and confirm the data's there via Kibana) the function keeps returning the original list to me. I can't get a list that includes my new data.

What am I doing wrong? Why won't my search update its results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probable reason **is that you are not paging**.

The [default size of search hits](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search) is controlled by "size" attribute provided in search request body and is 10 by default.

If you want to fetch next page of results, ask for that using size and from attributes in query api.

Comment: Yep, the original list I added happened to be 10 items, and that's why it kept returning those same 10 items. Adding the `size` arg fixed it. Thanks for the help!